# Android accessing asset file using case insensitive path?

Tags: java, android, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, android-assets

I want to access some asset files in Android AssetManager class, and the code is here.

`return form.getAssets().open(mediaPath);`

form.getAssets() returns an instance of AssetManager, and.open(mediapath)is supposed to open the asset with the given media path. However, my mediapath is case insensitive and Android asset file system is case sensitive. For example, I want to open an asset with path /asset/BALL.png using mediapath /asset/ball.png.

What is a good way to work around this? Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Best way to do is rename ball.png to ball2.png.

Comment: Thanks. I think that will work for one instance, but I'll trying to figure out a solution for general case